# Unable to fit nonlinear curve to data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to fit some data in Matlab to a Hill function of the form y = r^n/(r^n+K^n). I have data for r,y and I need to find K,n.

I tried two different approaches after reading the docs extensively - one uses `fit` from the CurveFitting Toolbox and the other uses `lsqcurvefit` from the Optimization Toolbox. I haven't had any success with either. What am I missing?

Here is my xdata and ydata:

```
xdata = logspace(-2,2,101);
ydata = [0.0981 0.1074 0.1177 0.1289 0.1411 0.1545 0.1692 0.1852 0.2027 ...
          0.2219 0.2428 0.2656 0.2905 0.3176 0.3472 0.3795 0.4146 0.4528 ...
          0.4944 0.5395 0.5886 0.6418 0.6994 0.7618 0.8293 0.9022 0.9808 ...
          1.0655 1.1566 1.2544 1.3592 1.4713 1.5909 1.7183 1.8537 1.9972 ...
          2.1490 2.3089 2.4770 2.6532 2.8371 3.0286 3.2272 3.4324 3.6437 ...
          3.8603 4.0815 4.3065 4.5344 4.7642 4.9950 5.2258 5.4556 5.6833 ...
          5.9082 6.1292 6.3457 6.5567 6.7616 6.9599 7.1511 7.3347 7.5105 ...
          7.6783 7.8379 7.9893 8.1324 8.2675 8.3946 8.5139 8.6257 8.7301 ...
          8.8276 8.9184 9.0029 9.0812 9.1539 9.2212 9.2834 9.3408 9.3939 ...
          9.4427 9.4877 9.5291 9.5672 9.6022 9.6343 9.6638 9.6909 9.7157 ...
          9.7384 9.7592 9.7783 9.7957 9.8117 9.8263 9.8397 9.8519 9.8630 ...
          9.8732 9.8826];
```

**'Fit' code:**

```
HillEqn = '@(x,xdata)xdata.^x(1)./(xdata.^x(1)+x(2).^x(1))';
startPoints = [1 1];
fit(xdata',ydata',HillEqn,'Start',startPoints)
```

*Error message:*

```
Error using fittype>iTestCustomModelEvaluation (line 726)
Expression @(x,xdata)xdata.^x(1)./(xdata.^x(1)+x(2).^x(1)) is not a valid MATLAB
expression, has non-scalar coefficients, or cannot be evaluated:
Undefined function 'imag' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
```

---

**'lsqcurvefit' code:**

```
fun = @(x,xdata) xdata.^x(1)./(xdata.^x(1)+x(2).^x(1));
x0 = [1,1]; % Initial Parameter Estimates
x = lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata);
```

*Error message:*

```
Error using snls (line 47)
Objective function is returning undefined values at initial point. lsqcurvefit cannot
continue.
```

Comment: Start by replacing `K.^n` with `K2`.  You can always take the n-th root later to get back your original constant, but simplifying the expression to fit should help convergence.

Comment: Most of the problem probably comes from you using expressions like `x^a` with negative `x` (see the first half of `xdata`) and fractional `a`. That's probably why you get an error quoting `imag`. But besides that: why pass a string containing a function handle rather than the handle itself? From [the doc of `fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#inputarg_fitType): "To fit custom models, use a MATLAB expression, a cell array of linear model terms, an anonymous function, or create a `fittype` with the `fittype` function and use this as the `fitType` argument."

Comment: And [you can avoid using a parameter array in your anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html#btpaend-11), it should be quite straightforward. Your model for negative exponents, however, is less trivial.

Comment: Your data looks nothing like [a Hill function](http://www.lacl.fr/~michel/research/hill).  Hill functions pass through the origin.

Comment: @BenVoigt and they're undefined for negative `x`, for good reason;)

Comment: @Andras: Yeah, I got `lsqcurvefit` to run by adding some `abs()` at appropriate places, but the quality of the fit was very poor to say the least (`n` approached 0).

Comment: Ok - I made a typo - `linspace` should be `logspace`. Given that, I tried both of your suggestions, and I am working on `fittype` now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think you need 3 variables to start from, because the hill function will be max of 1, and your data it is maxed at 10. So either normalize your data by doing `ydata=ydata./max(ydata)`, or add a 3rd variable (which I did just for the demonstration).  This is how I did it:

```
startPoints = [1 1 1];
s = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares',... %
    'Lower',[0    0   0  ],...
    'Upper',[inf  inf inf],...
    'Startpoint',startPoints);

HillEqn = fittype( 'x.^a1./(x.^a1+a2.^a1)*a3','options',s);
[ffun,gofrr] = fit(xdata(:),ydata(:),HillEqn);
yfit=feval(ffun,xdata(:)); %Fitted function
plot(xdata,ydata,'-bx',xdata,yfit,'-ro');
```

[image]

```
ffun = 

 General model:
 ffun(x) = x.^a1./(x.^a1+a2.^a1)*a3
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a1 =       1.004  (1.004, 1.004)
   a2 =      0.9977  (0.9975, 0.9979)
   a3 =       9.979  (9.978, 9.979)
```

**Side note:**

In your case what you really want to do is to transform you data by looking at  `Y=1./ydata` instead, then fit, and then take another `1./Y` to get the answer in the previous "hill" function representation. This is because your problem is bilinear in nature , so by going `1./ydata` you get a bilinear relation, for which a `polyfit` of order 1 will do:

```
Y=1./ydata;
X = 1./xdata;
p=polyfit(X,Y,1);
plot(X,Y,'-bx',X,polyval(p,X),'-ro')
```

[image]